# How do you skip testing stage in bamboo?

Tags: maven-3, bamboo

I'm using a `Maven` project from an `svn` in `Bamboo`. I was wondering if there is a way to skip the testing phase or at least skip a few specific tests through `Bamboo` settings (without modifying the code or `pom`)

Comment: Can you specify an option like `-DskipTests=true` to `mvn` command in Bamboo?

Comment: The only thing I was able to see is under `Maven 3.x Configuration` there is section for `Environment Variables` ((Optional) Any extra environment variables you want to pass to your build. e.g. MAVEN_OPTS="-Xmx256m -Xms128m". You can add multiple parameters separated by a space.). 

so i tried putting `-DskipTests=true` and also tried `-Dmaven.test.skip=true` but no success.

Comment: Just realized it's actually working, it still executes the tests, but even if they fail it will ignore it and move to the next phase. Thanks!

Answer (score 7, accepted):

under environment variables

`MAVEN_OPTS="-Dmaven.test.skip=true"`